# Is there a way to add a row to a Google Spreadsheet via a script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'd like to be able to call a script, which will add a row to a Google Spreadsheet, and manage stuff like user login. For example,

```
 gdocs_addrow --id <doc-id> name="John Doe" age="31"
```

I know there are nice Python APIs but I want to work at an even higher level.

My use case is that I want to make a script that uploads unit test results to a shared document.

Comment: This post might help out: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/48417/29140

Comment: Apparently this question is about programming by using python that has a stronger relationship with professional development than with  end-user programming.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote such a tool.  It's written in python, but designed to be used from the command line.  Have a look at [logss](https://github.com/happygiraffe/logss).  I've been using it to upload daily stats from a cron job.

Beware: I've not got great python installation skills, so running it is a little ad-hoc.

Answer (score -2):

If you want a row for each unit test, and for the command to *either* add a row *or* update an existing row then you need to have a key column. I've written&used this python library for similar problems: http://sheetsync.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Once you've installed it with:

```
pip install sheetsync
```

You could write a `gdocs_addrow.py` script like so:

```
import sys,sheetsync,argparse

def parse_cmd_line():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--id", metavar="GOOGLESHEET_KEY",required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--key", metavar="KEY_COLUMN_NAME",required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--sheet", metavar="WORKSHEET_NAME",default="Sheet1")
    parser.add_argument('fieldvals', metavar='FIELD=VALUE', nargs='+',
                       help="A list of FIELD=VALUE arguments")
    opts = parser.parse_args()
    opts.fieldvalue_dict = dict([fv.split("=") for fv in opts.fieldvals])
    if not opts.fieldvalue_dict.has_key(opts.key):
        print "'%s' specified as the key field, but not found in field=value list" %     opts.key
        sys.exit()
    opts.key_value = opts.fieldvalue_dict[opts.key]
    return opts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    opts = parse_cmd_line()
    target = sheetsync.Sheet(username="<YOUR_GOOGLE_USERNAME>", 
                    password="<PASSWORD_OR_APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD>",
                    document_key=opts.id,
                    sheet_name=opts.sheet,
                    key_column_headers=[opts.key])
    target.inject({opts.key_value:opts.fieldvalue_dict})
```

and use like this:

```
gdocs_addrow.py --id 1iZa...BqQ --key name name="Trevor B" age="31"
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does and how it helps?

Comment: @AndrewLott hope that's clearer.