# Automatically create a new row each day, on top of older rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am looking for a way to automatically create a new row on top of older rows each day.

Inside of this row should be the current date.

Comment: Were you able to implement my solution?

Comment: Approximately 340 rows were added since you asked this question.....

Answer (score 10):

With this little snippet it is possible. Add the code by selecting tools>Script editor in the spreadsheet. Make sure to press the `bug` button:

[image]

### Code

```
// for the active sheet (in essence the first)
function onTop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.insertRows(2);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  ss.getRange("A2").setValue(date);  
}

// for a specific sheet
function onTop() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("TEST");
  sh.insertRows(2);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  sh.getRange("A2").setValue(date);  
}
```

### Triggers

In the script editor, choose the following menu option:
[image]

and set the trigger as follows (or however you choose):
[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[on top](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEtLRWdFZmJTbFhHbjdDMXlBcW9lb3c&usp=sharing)**

### Remark

You have to return tomorrow to check it though =)

Comment: Hi Jacob! How would I modify this script to reference a particular tab? Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi @Drewdavid, see code I've added.

Comment: How do I set getRange(x) to below the last updated row? Like I want to update the sheet at the bottom.